# Automatic line break using detail summary element

Tags: html, css

I want to center the text of a summary. The text is centered but the text will be in a new line and the arrow for opening the details is in a separate line.

The desired look is that the arrow is in the same line as the summary content and also centered with it. The details shall be left aligned.

**Desired look**:
[image]

**Current source code ideas**:
But all of them have an additional line break after the arrow.

```css
    .center {
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

```html
<p>
  <details>
        <summary>
            <div class="center">
               Some summary in center
            </div>
        </summary>
        <div>
            <p>
               Some more details
            </p>
        </div>
    </details>
</p>
```

[image]

Comment: Is the image after your code what you have now and you want the image before your code?

Comment: The image after the code is how it is looking with the source code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your `.center` class in the `<summary>` tag:

```css
.center {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<details>
    <summary class="center">
           Some summary in center       
    </summary>
        <p>
           Some more details
        </p>
</details>
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. In my tests I left the div element and then there was an additional line break.